# Best practice for writing lots of similar functions/processes

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, theory

I have some language agnostic and design pattern related question although I am programming in javascript/node.js if it matters.
It is actually very simple and maybe trivial for some experienced programmers.

Lets say we have a function/method that does some process (call it business logic) by calling other functions which are dealing with specific sub-problems.

```
function doProcess(){
subProcessA();
subProcessB();
subProcessC();

return "OK"
}
```

But then, we get task to do similar process but this new process must not call subProcessA.
So for example we have next part of code:

```
function doProcess2(){
subProcessB();
subProcessC();

return "OK"
}
```

So my question is how to design code or should I:

A) Make every time new function for new process like in upper example but then I have lots of redundant code and repeating myself every time.

B) Do big IF in process code like this one:

```
if(some-condition){
    subProcessA()
 }
```

But then my code will look very bad.

C) Migrate that IF directly in subprocessA :

```
if(!some-condition){
     return // do nothing
}
```

but again it looks like coupled code and also I have a feeling that it is not best approach.

D) Something else?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the concrete code you are working with. It is even more true for JavaScript, since you can almost the same task in many different ways. I know this is a pretty generic answer. However, your description is kind of a facade pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to the point where it matters how frequently you call a subFunctionN() for performing that sub-task. Now if you have a linear dependency wherein you need to call a sub-function right before another sub-function, and if this coupling is more predominant in your code than this coupling should be made a part of a separate sub-function which performs more than just one sub-task.

for e.g:

```
Function MasterFunctionA(){
    subFunctionCouplet_12();
    subFunction3();
}

Function MasterFunctionB(){
    subFunction1();
    subFunction3();
}

Function subFunctionCouplet_12(){
    subFunction1();
    subFunction2();
}

Function subFunction1(){
    //do something here...
}

Function subFunction2(){
    // do something here...
}

Function subFunction3(){
    // do something here...
}
```

Though this is just an example of how to modularize your code for not repeating yourself, the actual implementation for your code will be purely based on your liking of modularization. The basic guidelines to follow here are that you do not repeat the actual business logic in more than one function, but the encapsulating function can be repeated any number of times throughout your code, given that you can keep the repetition to a minimum.